# Razor Ajax.ActionLink Not Updating Html.EditFor Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, razor

I've been trying and searching to figure this one out with no avail.
I'm using an Ajax helper "@Ajax.ActionLink" in my Razor file (Asp.net MVC) to update an html helper "@Html.EditorFor" control. It works perfectly when the Ajax option "UpdateTargetId" is set to another element such as span , but not with @Html.EditorFor. When the Ajax option "InsertionMode.ReplaceWith" is applied, it replaces the @Html.EditorFor control with a read-only element like span. The Ajax option "InsertionMode.Replace" doesn't apply any changes to the @Html.EditorFor control. Code example below. Thanks for any help.

```
    AjaxOptions objOP_Options = new AjaxOptions();

    objOP_Options.HttpMethod = "GET";

    objOP_Options.UpdateTargetId = ("Cost");

    objOP_Options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;


    <td align="left">
       <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
             small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span></small>
          </span>
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form- 
                          control", @style = "width:75px", @id = "Cost", @onChange = 
                          "totalCost(); format_num(id)" } })
        </div>
     </td>

     <td>
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Calc. Cost", "Get_Cost", "ControllerName", new
            {
                Param1 = Model.Field1,
                Param2 = Model.Field2,
                Param3 = Model.Field3,
                Param4 = Model.Field4
            }, objOP_Options)
     </td>

      <span id="dataCost"></span>   //this would work when set as UpdateTargetId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied an alternative approach to solve this matter.
Instead of using the Ajax.ActionLink, I called a Java Script function on a button click (which sequentially called another Java Script function that implemented the Ajax call) to update the Html.EditFor control.
Hope this helps for those of you who may have the same issue.